# How to validate a ISO Format (YYYY-MM-DD) date validation in libreoffice or VBA. If its other than YYYY-MM-DD it should give me an error message

Tags: excel, vba, libreoffice

Have to check the date format validation in my code

If it's `YYYY-MM-DD` it is okay to proceed, otherwise exit the loop

something like this

```
if date is not in YYYY-MM-DD format  
  Msgbox "please enter a valid format of YYYY-MM-DD  
exit     
else  
   all those calcualtions  
end if
```

Comment: First use `Like` to test for the general digital pattern, and if matches, use `Mid` to test individual parts for allowed numeric ranges.

Comment: Can you please provide me a sample code that I can work upon

Answer (score 1):

## Use this function:

If you're getting the results from a non-user source this should work.  If the data is coming from a user I would test it for being any valid date and then convert into the format you need.

```
Function TestDate(D As String) As String
    Dim X As Date
    
    On Error GoTo inval
    
    If Len(D) = 10 Then
        X = CDate(D)
        TestDate = Format(X, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    Else
        TestDate = "Invalid"
    End If
    
    Exit Function
    
inval:
    TestDate = "Invalid"
End Function
```

Comment: Somebody manually will enter the data in the spreadsheet and if its not in the format of YYYY-MM-DD my vba code should pop up a message that Please enter the date in proper format.

Comment: This code takes a string as an argument and tells you if it is a valid date or not. Is there a reason you have to validate the ISO format? Why not just test for general date validity and the convert the date to the ISO format?

Comment: Yes there is reason for this. My excel will go into the BO reports so the requirement is that users are only allowed to enter the ISO date formar i.e. YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: So I just want to validate the format. No need to convert it into any other format.

Comment: Then I would just test the user input to be a date in any format and then pass a value that you convert into the reports.  I can update my answer to do that if you want me to.

Comment: See the thing is I have to validate date only in YYYY-MM-DD format not in any format. Do have anything for the format validation ?

Comment: I think you don't understand me.  You don't have to validate the dates in this format if you are passing them to another program.  You can validate that it is a valid date in any format and then pass the date in the correct format to BO.  You don't want your users to have to put up with that.  And they'll find that much more impressive.

Comment: I totally understand you. But there are some other conditions also which requires users to enter only ISO date format. and also BO stuff is by some other team. My requirement is that I allow users to enter only ISO dates i.e. YYYY-MM-DD. Thanks

Comment: Ok.  I'm done.  The reason why your question isn't getting answers and is getting down votes is because it is a non-issue.  A date is a date and there is no reason to require a user to enter a date in a specific format.  If a down-stream application requires a specific format you can pass it in that format using a simple Format() command.

Comment: Okay. Not a pblm. Basically I was just looking for a regex or anything for the date validation. Like you validate the pattern with regex , similar like that

Comment: You can use RegEx with VBA, but it's hit or miss if the library will be installed on everyone's computer.  In our company we are supposed to have a standard drive image, but only about 50% of users can use the RegEx addin.  The best way to do what you're asking is a Format(CDate("Date"),"YYYY-MM-DD"), but you'll have to use error handling and validate the years because 0001 and 9999 are both valid ISO years.

Comment: Do you have any example of the above ?

Comment: How can I run this inside a sub, getting an error message that function is not allowed inside a sub

Comment: To be honest this answer was misleading and generally unhelpful